# Angular - mat-autocomplete to mat-select-search

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular8, dropdown, angular-forms

```
<mat-form-field>
     <mat-label>ce Type</mat-label>
       <input placeholder="Select type" matInput formControlName="e_id" [matAutocomplete]="cotype">
          <mat-autocomplete #cotype="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">
            <mat-option *ngIf="isLoading" class="is-loading">Loading...</mat-option>
               <ng-container *ngIf="!isLoading">
                   <mat-option *ngFor="let ce of ceList" [value]="ce.id">
                       {{ce.name}}
                   </mat-option>
               </ng-container>
          </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

How to change my searchable dropdown to mat-select-search.... In the above html I used for search how to change the this html to mat-select-search....